# Why does this fail with "'async for' requires an object with __aiter__ method, got coroutine"

Tags: python, python-asyncio, google-cloud-ai

I am attempting to call an external API (one that is provided by Google) using an async client library (the library is also provided by Google).

The async method that I am attempting to call is `async list_featurestores()` ([documentation](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/aiplatform/latest/google.cloud.aiplatform_v1.services.featurestore_service.FeaturestoreServiceAsyncClient#google_cloud_aiplatform_v1_services_featurestore_service_FeaturestoreServiceAsyncClient_list_featurestores)). It provides the following sample code:

```py
from google.cloud import aiplatform_v1

async def sample_list_featurestores():
    # Create a client
    client = aiplatform_v1.FeaturestoreServiceAsyncClient()

    # Initialize request argument(s)
    request = aiplatform_v1.ListFeaturestoresRequest(
        parent="parent_value",
    )

    # Make the request
    page_result = client.list_featurestores(request=request)

    # Handle the response
    async for response in page_result:
        print(response)
```

(I've literally copy/pasted that code from the above linked page).

In order to run that code I've slightly adapted it to:

```py
import asyncio
from google.cloud import aiplatform_v1

async def sample_list_featurestores():
    client = aiplatform_v1.FeaturestoreServiceAsyncClient()
    request = aiplatform_v1.ListFeaturestoresRequest(parent="projects/MY_GCP_PROJECT/locations/europe-west2",)
    page_result  = client.list_featurestores(request=request)
    async for response in page_result:
        print(response)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(sample_list_featurestores())
```

When I run it it fails on this line:
`async for response in page_result:` with error:

> 'async for' requires an object with **aiter** method, got coroutine

This is my first foray into async python development and, given I (think I) have followed the supplied code to the letter I don't know why I'm getting this error.

Am I missing something obvious here? Can someone explain how to get past this error?

Comment: Hitting the same error with `documentai` service - these `list_xxx` methods do not seem to return true async generators. Did you find a workaround ?

Comment: As list is usually small, I used the blocking sync client to call the list method. These correctly return generators.

Comment: Why did you revert your post to a version with a broken link?

Comment: Which link is broken? I only see one link in this post (https://googleapis.dev/python/aiplatform/latest/aiplatform_v1/featurestore_service.html) and it is not broken. It does lead somewhere, even if it uses a redirect. I reverted your edit because it hyperlinked the word "here" which I dislike (this explains why: https://heyoka.medium.com/dont-use-click-here-f32f445d1021).

Comment: Okay, display the URL if you prefer, but keep the nice link to the specific section... Also if you want a descriptive link *and* a less cluttered post, why not something like "([documentation] here)"? The article you linked to specifically recommends against using URLS themselves as links.

Comment: (Or just make the method itself a link, that is what you're linking to after all.)

Comment: Looks weird, their example seems broken. Maybe a package version problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try using "await":

```
# Make the request
page_result = await client.list_featurestores(request=request)
```